# How to compress/reduce size of a video recorded with cordova-plugin-media-capture?

Tags: ionic3

I've implemented a program that record videos (both Android/iOS) with `cordova-plugin-media-capture` and upload them to a server.

It's working very well, but the videos that have just a few seconds have more than 10 mb and we need to reduce this size...

We already tried to change the `quality` parameter of `CaptureVideoOptions`, but it only accept 1 (hight quality) or 0 (poor quality).

If I set `quality: 0`, the video is saved in `.3gp` rather than `.mp4` and the quality is awful. We didn't find a way to record the videos with 70% of quality, for instance.

Anybody there knows a way to compress a video file or to record with an acceptable quality?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, have found a solution for this ? ^^

Comment: Unfortunately this was a long time ago, I don't have access to the project anymore and can't remember how I've fixed this... :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I found that the plugin cordova-plugin-video-editor does this job very well :) https://github.com/AlexMiniApps/cordova-plugin-video-editor